# SOLR phrase query not returning result

Tags: solr

If I search for `order of merit` without quotes, I get results returned. The first result has "order of merit" in it. But if I do an exact match by adding quotes `"order of merit"` I get zero results returned. What's going on here? What do I have to do to get an exact match?

Answer (score 0):

Solr difference between searching term only or an whole phrase. Depending on the query parser you are using.

For example: if you use the edismax query parser, there are some explicit parameter to define, how phrase-queries should be handled:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#pf_.28Phrase_Fields.29

Probably it's an good idea to check your `solrconfig.xml` against that.